# Jitsi Meet - You have been disconnected

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I just followed the "Quick Start" instructions here:

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker

and then did the changes below:

```
diff --git a/.env b/.env
index 6216b49..4e5e235 100644
--- a/.env
+++ b/.env
@@ -10,22 +10,22 @@
 #
 
 # XMPP component password for Jicofo
-JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET=
+JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET=633e7a05fe12956618dac1d41ce8c1d1
 
 # XMPP password for Jicofo client connections
-JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD=
+JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD=8d17f2200b8110a8dd67a8a9fb30f197
 
 # XMPP password for JVB client connections
-JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD=
+JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD=bc78308fa2850a548e842c2d1db3542d
 
 # XMPP password for Jigasi MUC client connections
-JIGASI_XMPP_PASSWORD=
+JIGASI_XMPP_PASSWORD=de411859c3ef5b093bc45c921d59f243
 
 # XMPP recorder password for Jibri client connections
-JIBRI_RECORDER_PASSWORD=
+JIBRI_RECORDER_PASSWORD=a42fdf73c35d978e33fb353cff108df6
 
 # XMPP password for Jibri client connections
-JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=
+JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=564450347551ff8d5a0217e09a6b576d
 
 
 #
@@ -36,16 +36,16 @@ JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=
 CONFIG=~/.jitsi-meet-cfg
 
 # Exposed HTTP port
-HTTP_PORT=8000
+HTTP_PORT=80
 
 # Exposed HTTPS port
-HTTPS_PORT=8443
+HTTPS_PORT=443
 
 # System time zone
 TZ=UTC
 
 # Public URL for the web service (required)
-#PUBLIC_URL=https://meet.example.com
+PUBLIC_URL=https://jitsi.mydummyserver.com
 
 # IP address of the Docker host
 # See the "Running behind NAT or on a LAN environment" section in the Handbook:
@@ -63,16 +63,16 @@ TZ=UTC
 #
 
 # Enable Let's Encrypt certificate generation
-#ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT=1
+ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT=1
 
 # Domain for which to generate the certificate
-#LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN=meet.example.com
+LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN=jitsi.mydummyserver.com
 
 # E-Mail for receiving important account notifications (mandatory)
-#LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=alice@atlanta.net
+LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=contact@mydummyserver.com
 
 # Use the staging server (for avoiding rate limits while testing)
-#LETSENCRYPT_USE_STAGING=1
+LETSENCRYPT_USE_STAGING=1
 
 
 #
@@ -353,4 +353,4 @@ JIBRI_LOGS_DIR=/config/logs
 RESTART_POLICY=unless-stopped
 
 # Authenticate using external service or just focus external auth window if there is one already.
-# TOKEN_AUTH_URL=https://auth.meet.example.com/{room}
+# TOKEN_AUTH_URL=https://auth.jitsi.mydummyserver.com/{room}
\ No newline at end of file
```

but I got the error: "You have been disconnected".

[image]

The website loads and the HTTPS is working fine, though.

Any idea on what's going on and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had same reconnect-message in infinite loop. Using "stable-5076" did not help me. But when I change .env-file in one string it helped me. I uncomment PUBLIC_URL string and write PRIVATE IP of computer where is jitsi installed. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue with Jitsi Meet docker on RedHat installation.

Configuring two things in `.env` solved my issue

```
# Public URL for the web service (required)
PUBLIC_URL=<PUBLIC_URL_WITH_CERTS>

# IP address of the Docker host
# See the "Running behind NAT or on a LAN environment" section in the Handbook:
# https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker#running-behind-nat-or-on-a-lan-environment
DOCKER_HOST_ADDRESS=<YOUR_PRIVATE_IP>
```

Also, the PUBLIC_URL is the `Reverse Proxy` URL which has the certificate configured.

> <MY_HOST>:443 --> <DOCKER_HOST>:8443

**PRIVATE IP** address in case you are using cloud-like AWS/Azure/GCP

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a new version :

image: jitsi/{web,prosody,jicofo,jvb}:stable-5076 work perfectly.

I had the same problems as you before using the version there